# Soft Return detection?

Tags: xml, xslt, return

In my xslt, I wonder if there is a way to tell whether there is a shift-return? My client used AdobeFrameMaker to make the xml file, and some of the table cells look like this:

```
<CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="2">
   <TableBodyCenter>
         <A ID="pgfId-129001"/> HWWG51M0M0(5/8-11 x 5/8)
   </TableBodyCenter>
</CELL>
```

According to what they said, there should be a "shift-return" in front of the "(" in the above string inside the `<TableBodyCenter>` tag.

But I don't see anything there, is it possible to detect that in XSLT? or if there is a way that I can tell them such a "shift return" doesn't exist at all in the above xml node.

Comment: Forget about detecting it in XSLT. Can you detect it in Notepad or other plain-text editor?

Comment: "shift-return" should generate a normal NL character, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for `Shift-Return` using the [contains() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195.aspx):

```
<xsl:if test="contains(TableBorderCenter/text(), '&#xA;'">
    <!-- -->
</xsl:if>
```

Depending on which xslt processor you're using, you may be able to instruct it to not strip whitespace from text nodes.

Comment: I am using Saxon8, is it a processing instruction ?